# InputStream and OutputStream should be closed in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I'm a bit confused about `InputStream` and `OutputStream` in Codename One: because in the javadoc of their `close` methods reports that:

> The close method of InputStream does nothing.
>
> The close method of OutputStream does nothing.

I (erroneously?) assumed that I don't need to use them because they do nothing. So I never used them in my code... but I noted now that the JavaSE 8 javadocs report the same sentences...

Have I to use them? Is there any consequence in not using them in Codename One?

Thank you for any explanation.

- https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/java/io/InputStream.html#close--
- https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/java/io/OutputStream.html#close--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they should be closed because the subclasses override the methods and do something. The JavaDoc should probably be improved to indicate that.

For 99.9% of the cases GC will handle close properly for you (it's implicit) so you should be OK on current devices. So you don't need to be too stressed about this.